# Is there a way to slice an x,y array diagonally?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, slice

I have a 3D array (time, y direction, x direction), and I want to split it up spatially. However, is there a way to slice a spatial array diagonally instead of just in y and x?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(100,45,60)

data_1 = data[:,0:30,0:30]

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,60,1),np.arange(0,45,1))


plt.contourf(X,Y,data[2])
plt.show()

plt.contourf(data_1[2])
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

first graph shows the contour plot if **data**, and then the **data_1**, but is there a way to slice it diagonally? For example, where the red line is.

By slicing I mean selecting only sections of the 3D data array in x and y direction. For example get only the data under the red arrow.

Comment: what do you mean with "slice"? What is the thing you want to have as an output?

Comment: Agreed with Marcus. In addition notice that you can classify the data under the diagonal by x+y < 30, and above the diagonal by x+y > 30 if you have 30x30 matrix.

Comment: Oh yes! @Tristan, I think that may be accomplishing what I am trying to do. I will update question right now to indicate what i meant about slicing

Comment: in order to do x + y >30... in my case, would I do that by: X + Y > 30... plt.contourf(X,Y, data_1)?

Comment: Do you want to slice the plot, or the data? If the plot, one part should probably be set to 0, or NaN. If the data, do you want to transform the data shape (to a smaller 2D array, or to a 1D array), or set values in one half to e.g. 0 or NaN, or mask them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(5,45,60)
data1 = data[2,0:30,0:30]
x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 30, 1), np.arange(0, 30, 1))
data1 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 30, data1)

plt.contourf(x2, y2, data1)
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()
```

I have used a masked array above, but it is also possible to use `np.where` instead and set values to `np.NaN`:

```
data1 = np.where(x2 + y2 > 30, np.NaN, data1)
```

Matplotlib will also not plot NaN values.

Setting values to NaN, however, will lose the original values, while a mask simply hides them (removing the mask will retrieve the original values). NaNs can also be tricky in comparisons. So a mask may be better.

[image]